# Fixed height and width imageview with large size bitmap issue

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I am trying to set bitmap of higher size to imageview of fixed height and width,

Imageview in xml

```
 <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
       android:layout_width="320dp"
       android:layout_height="180dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

When i am using the following code error is avoided but the image appeared is blurred because of BitmapFactory.Options options,

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/"+photo, options);
            imgMainItem.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

What else are the option available of setting a image of higher size and fixed height and width please help

Answer (score 2):

Don't used a fixed sample size. Calculate the sample size you need first, like so:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Then, use it like so:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/"+photo;
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
imgMainItem.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

`width` and `height` is your required width and height in pixels.

If your bitmap is a *lot* smaller than the size you want, you can't really scale it up without it being blurry. Use a higher-quality bitmap.

Comment: -Ken Wolf No its throwing me the error Out of memory on a 40144912-byte allocation.

Comment: What values did you put for reqWidth and reqHeight?

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 300, 250);

Comment: I edited my answer - please try again. You need to run `decodeFile` twice - first with `inJustDecodeBounds = true` to get the dimensions and then with false.